# What is the most efficient way to generate a UUID in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, uuid

Is there a significant overhead (CPU, memory and/or IO) in making repeat calls to the following function:

```
public function getUuid()
{
    return `uuidgen -r`; # -r = version 4
}
```

Versus using an [all PHP implementation of generating a UUID](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/blob/master/src/Uuid.php) (v4)?  If it matters the project is using `Apache (Prefork MPM) 2.2.22` and `PHP 5.3.10` (with `APC`).

My initial feeling would be that the benefit of doing the generation of the UUID in a C library instead of in PHP would more than make up for the system call overhead.  Additionally with `uuidgen` being part of the `util-linux` package I would inherently trust it more than a PHP library to generate the UUIDs correctly, but I'm keen to get some extra input.

Comment: couldn't you use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: @dagon we are integrating with some non-PHP systems, so being able to generate the same style of identifiers across all systems is important.

Comment: I wonder what the guys who closed this are thinking. This is clearly a programming question that would be off-topic on SuperUser.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I feel very strongly that this is a programming question and it should be reopened. I'm using PHP and I need to generate a UUID in an efficient way and my question is about the differences to my code between using PHP to call a system library or use an all PHP implementation to generate it.

Comment: You might still consider my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you profile the problem. The `shell_exec()` PHP function also spawns a shell, so it might not come as cheap as you think. However the PHP class you mention also seems to call subprocesses. I did some tests (on OS X) and could generate 10.000 UUIDs with the PHP class in about a minute, opposed to 40 seconds with `shell_exec('uuidgen')`.

The PHP class also seems to call `ifconfig` in addition to `shell_exec()`, so that might be the reason for the slightly bigger overhead.

Also the results will probably vary with the hash algorithm you choose.